# Read a matrix file into Android

Tags: android, xml, file-io, matrix, mat

I'm trying to read a big matrix from MATLAt and read it on my android.  Would you convert it to text and read it from a text file, or XML file? How do you read it and display it to the user?

Answer (score 0):

Try JSON - it's much more like a Matrix -

http://www.json.org/

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33381-jsonlab-a-toolbox-to-encodedecode-json-files-in-matlaboctave

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

As for display, that really depends on what you're after - You could use a TextView or some custom solution